# Easily way to designer workflows for Alfresco Content Services

Tags: editor, alfresco, alfresco-share, bpmn

I know the Alfresco Process Services are not free, so what's the best option (Free) for development (BMP Designer) workflows for run direct into Alfresco Community?

I tried without success:

- Activiti Plugin for Eclipse, but it required a hard work to make flows, forms and to export to Alfresco Community.
- Activiti Community (web platform), but is not compatible with Alfresco content Services workflow engine.

How can I easily designer my flows for run in Alfresco Content Services (Community)?

Comment: Eclipse + Alfresco model definitions + forms config is the "normal" way, it's not too bad once you get the hang of it

Comment: Hi Gagravarr,Thanks for your response. I would like the end user can create/edit his flows. So Activiti Plugin for Eclipse is not viable.

Comment: If you really want your users to be able to design, you'll need the Activiti online / Alfresco Process Services option. IIRC you'll need to pony up for the Enterprise version of Alfresco to be able to make use of Process Services within the Alfresco Repo+Share

Comment: In activiti explorer (5.22) there was an online editor. I made it reusable/embeddable, you may have a look at it. [link](https://github.com/jmalyik/simple_bpmn_editor)

Comment: Hi m4gic, Do your bmp editor provide to build forms too ?